# Can't start the SSH service in CentOS V6.9

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, services

Currenlty ssh service is in stop status.when we trying to start this service following error shows;

**'/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 23: directive 'protocol' is not allowed within a match block'.**
[image]

How to fix this issue and start ths ssh service

Here is the first part of the config file:
[image]

Comment: Can you post your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`? It looks like you need to end your match block before using the `Protocol` directive

Comment: From the top of your screenshot to the `Protocol 2` line, I count 19 lines, not 23. So is there anything that includes the word `Match` in the first 4 lines that are not visible? (In an unedited `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file from RHEL 6.9, that `Protocol 2`line seems to be line 21, not 23. So it looks like this file has been edited at some point.)

Comment: @rusty shackleford : sorry can't get the entire data beacuse we can not login to the server.Only can access via vnc.

Comment: @telcoM I have attached the first part of the ssh config file..

Comment: I have comment first to lines.It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add this on line 3:

```
Match all
```

You have not ended the `Match` block.

Comment: I added this line but couldn't start ssh. I have comment those first two lines and start.It works. Anyway thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

The first two lines have apparently been added as part of a chroot jail set-up for user `restricted_user_1`.

Since that user is apparently related to system backups, I think it's kind of important... so a better solution would be to move those two lines to the end of the sshd_config file instead. That should both avoid the problem with the Protocol 2 line and not break the setup of `restricted_user_1` user.

If you use `Match` blocks in `sshd_config`, then the ordering of lines in the file is important.

- you should place any configuration lines that should be the default settings before any `Match` blocks. Some configuration options cannot be used within Match blocks: those options should always be placed before any `Match` block.
- when a `Match` block begins, it will only end either at the start of another `Match` block or at end-of-file. A `Match` block can be used to conditionally override some of the default settings. Anything after the first `Match` block until end-of-file will belong to one `Match` block or another.